# AWK help filter data into CSV

Tags: awk

We are doing some security research for which I need to extract from Debian repos all available package names, versions, desc, etc.

I'm trying to parse output of `apt-cache dumpavail` into CSV and organise data into tabular form like name, version, desc.

I'm not very good at AWK but I guess its the perfect tool for this ? Feel free recommend me the ways I can make a good regex for AWK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `sed` might be better suited, e.g. with GNU sed:

*parse.sed*

```sed
/^Package: /                { s///; h }
/^Version: |^Description: / { s///; H }
/^$/                        { x; s/\n/;/gp }
```

Explanation:

- Locate lines starting with the desired prefixes, e.g. `/^Package/`
- Remove the prefix `s///`, i.e. substitute the previously matched pattern with nothing
- Save the rest to hold-space (`h`) or (`H`), note the `h` overwrites hold-space
- When an inter-package empty line is encountered (`/^$/`), swap hold-space and pattern-space (`x`) and substitute new-lines with the desired delimiter, here semi-colon (`s/\n/;/gp`) and print the result

Run it like this:

```
apt-cache dumpavail | sed -nEf parse.sed
```

With `head` attached the output is:

```
0ad;0.0.23-1+b1;Real-time strategy game of ancient warfare                
0ad-data;0.0.23-1;Real-time strategy game of ancient warfare (data files)
0ad-data-common;0.0.23-1;Real-time strategy game of ancient warfare (common data files)
0xffff;0.8-1;Open Free Fiasco Firmware Flasher
2048-qt;0.1.6-1+b1;mathematics based puzzle game
2ping;4.2-1;Ping utility to determine directional packet loss
2vcard;0.6-1;perl script to convert an addressbook to VCARD file format
fonts-3270;2.0.0-1;monospaced font based on IBM 3270 terminals
389-admin;1.1.46-2;389 Directory Administration Server
libds-admin-serv0;1.1.46-2;Libraries for the 389 Directory Administration Server
```

Comment: Works perfectly...very nice explanation and well working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some Perl. Requires Text::CSV from CPAN

```
apt-cache dumpavail | perl -MText::CSV -00 -ane '
    BEGIN {
        $csv = Text::CSV->new({eol=>"\n"});
        @wanted = qw/Package Version Architecture Description/;
        $csv->print(STDOUT, \@wanted);
        $re = "(" . join("|", @wanted) . "): (.+?)(?=\\Z|^[[:upper:]])";
    }
    %m = /$re/msg; 
    for $key (keys %m) {$m{$key} =~ s/\n//g} 
    $csv->print(STDOUT, [@m{@wanted}]);
' > avail.csv
```